# php NumberFormatter format to spelling

Tags: php, numberformatter

hi im using php `NumberFormatter` in `laravel`
now if i want to echo number i did this code

```
@php
   $digit = new \NumberFormatter(Lang::locale(), \NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
   echo $digit->format(round(10.557,3));
@endphp
```

the result will be
[image]
but i need it to be

```
ten and five handred and seventy five
```

how can i change the format ..
thanks ..

Comment: How do you expect 557 to turn into five hundred and seventy five?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to build a function manually

```
function numberToText($number) {
  $digit = new \NumberFormatter(Lang::locale(), \NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
  $numberParts = explode('.', (string) round($number,3));
  $formatedNumber =  $digit->format($numberParts[0]);
  if (isset($numberParts[1] ) {
    $formatedNumber .= ' and ' . $digit->format($numberParts[1]);
  }
  return $formatedNumber;
}

@php
  echo numberToText(10.557);
@endphp
```